# How to extract epoch from date in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, epoch

AWS's Redshift provides the [extract function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_EXTRACT_function.html):

`EXTRACT ( datepart FROM { TIMESTAMP 'literal' | timestamp } )`

The `datepart` takes [various values](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Dateparts_for_datetime_functions.html) including `epoch` - you can therefore extract the epoch from a `timestamp` e.g.

`select extract(epoch from {timestamp_column_name});`

**Is it possible to extract the epoch from a date field?**

`select extract(epoch from {date_column_name});`

If not, **how can I convert a date field into a timestamp?**

`select extract(epoch from {expression to convert {date_column_name} to timestamp});`

Comment: "convert a date field into a timestamp" - `date_column::timestamp`?

Comment: yes that's handy. what happens if I do `timestamp_column::timestamp`. Can one use the same query for both `date` and `timestamp` columns?

Comment: Have you tried `extract(epoch from date_column::timestamp)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible to extract the epoch from a date field? yes

```
Select extract(epoch from getdate()::date)
```

Comment: the `getdate` function returns a `timestamp` type not a `date` type

link to docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_GETDATE.html

Comment: @mattgathu I believe getdate() is not you column, this is just an example.. and you can always covert using :: date

Comment: I know that you can `extract`  `epoch` from a `timestamp` field. But the docs are not clear if it's possible to `extract` `epoch` from a `date` field. That's my question.